# EE-Student Electronics problem ( Diodes)

Tags: diodes

I'm studying, at the moment, at university, Electronics 1, and struggling to understand how to solve this circuit. I tried to solve it, and these are my results and thinking.

The forward voltage drop for the diodes is Vz = 0.65(V). D11 and D10 are the same.

I need to find the voltage across D10 and D11 and the current through them.

This is how I solved it.
The current is obtained from the formula I = (V1+V2)/R1 = 8.55(mA).
Because the D11 is inversed polarized is not conducting current, so it's 0.
The current through D10 is the same current through the circuit, 8.55(mA) and the voltage is 0.65(V)
I don't know how to find the voltage of D11.

[image: Circuit Figure]

Comment: You know the forward voltage drop across the conducting diode and the reverse-biased diode is connected in parallel with it.

Comment: Yes you do ... what is it in parallel with?

Comment: If I enter the circuit in Falstad, it's showing the voltage drop on D11 is -450 mV and that got me confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To know what the voltage across the diode is, you need to know the type of diode.  Is it a schottky or a standard silicon diode etc.?
Also, there is the "rule of thumb" voltage drop of  a diode and then there is the (more accurate) forward drop due to the amount of current flowing through it, which is given in the datasheet for the specific diode in question.

Lastly, your equation for calculating the current is missing a voltage.

> I don't know how to find the voltage of D11

From physics, if two elements are in parallel, what is the voltage across them?

Comment: If two elements are in parallel, the voltage is the same on both elements. 
The diodes are standard silicon diodes. 
I entered the circuit in Falstad, and it's saying that the voltage on D11 is 450mV. That got me confusing so this is why I'm asking. 
As for the current formula, I should subtract the voltage of D10?

Comment: @AlexHrenciuc Correct, subtract the diode voltage.

Comment: @AlexHrenciuc Falstad is either using a I-V curve, which means the voltage will change with current.  Or it is using a type of schottky with a higher Vf.  Try increasing the current to see if the diode voltage changes.

Comment: @AlexHrenciuc If the I-V is changing, just use the diode Vf that your teacher gave you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to find the voltage of D11.

You already know what it is. It's the voltage across D10. They are all in parallel, after all, and that's what a parallel connection means: that the voltages across the parallel-connected elements are the same. That's one of the many equivalent definitions of a parallel connection, in fact!